# Magento: How to change default template dynamically in controllers

Tags: php, ajax, magento

example: a controller named ajaxhandlerController
   it can receive several ajax request types,
   each type should have separate block in the layout xml

in layout for index of ajaxhandler i would write

```
  <mymodule_ajaxhandler_index>
      <block some block></block>
  </mymodule_ajaxhandler_index>
```

How do I change from index to save for example if there is $request['type']=="save"; so I can use

```
  <mymodule_ajaxhandler_save>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would forget about layout XML. An simply instantiate a Core_Block_Html_Template and assign the correct template to using the setTemplate method according the the request type received.

```
$html = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/template')
        ->setTemplate('your/template.phtml')
        ->toHtml();
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but using this doesn't go through the module/block chain of code. so the result an empty template block. while using what's in the layout.xml works fine, I made a new controller for save and it pulled off the template correctly. any suggestions?

Comment: have you echoed the $html hehe :)

Comment: yes of course I did (;  I already tried that method before you answer, and what I meant by empty block, I mean empty from data. what I want it to show is "you chose XX"  when I use the corresponding layout xml .it shows up correctly, when I use create block , it simply displays block without the data. what it seems to me it is not using the parent methods of the block. I need investigate further

Comment: do you have a block class that gives you the data you want to display in the template. In that case say you have This_Is_Block_Class extend Mage_Core_Bloack_Template in it put the methods that will return the value of XX and in the template simply call the method since $this within the template will refer to your class [This_Is_Block_Class].

Comment: yes the template has such block .  I did a test now, I put echo get_class($this); in the template   and what happens when using createblock it shows Mage_Core_Block_Template   ,while when using a layout .xml  it displays my block class name correctly.  I tried $this->getLayout()->getBlock("mymodule/blockname") or createBlock("mymodule/blockname")

Comment: createBlock("mymodule/blockname") should work and get_class($this) in template should print your class. Any errors in system.log or exception.log when you try to use that??

Comment: when I do this, I noticed firebug reports 500 internal server error.  weird, I checked logs, error log, magento logs. apache logs nothing so far. I ll keep checking, but if you have any suggestion, I appreciate it.